# c++ regex not working as expected (regex_search)

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I currently am working on regex in c++ in which I tried to search a substring in a string.

Problem :

String :

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard">
Options +Indexes
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In this I need only the first Directory contents,that is

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Hence I used the regex

```
Regex : < *Directory *\/? *>(\n.*?)+<\/Directory>
```

In this regex I used a **\n.*?** so that it will return the first result(lazy). It works fine when I tried in https://regexr.com but when I use regex_search it shows there isn't a match. How is this possible? Am I missing out anything?

Code :

```
LPSTR logLocation = "C:\\xampp\\apache\\conf\\httpd.conf";

string logBuffer = RemoveCommentsFromFile(logLocation);

//cout<<logBuffer;

smatch match;
regex regx("< *Directory *\/? *>(\n.*?)+<\/Directory>");

if(regex_search(logBuffer,match,regx))
    cout<<match.str();
```

The code basically removes comments from a file and returns it as string.

Comment: Are you sure your line breaks are LF? Try `< *Directory */? *>(?:\r?\n.*?)*?</Directory>` to match an optional CR if it is there before LF.

Comment: yeah tried strstr and checked whether there are any CR in it and it returned false.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to repro.

Comment: convert it to `regex regx(R"(< *Directory *\/? *>(\n.*?)+<\/Directory>)");`

Comment: I can't test it right now, but don't you have to escape the `\` in `\n` (as in `\\n`)?

Comment: I did that too. I escaped \n sometime back and yet it's not working!

Comment: Cannot [reproduce](https://onlinegdb.com/SJTfVahfm) (after changing `\n` to `\\n` it works). I guess the new line character is `\r\n` since you seem to use windows, and in this case after changing `\n` to `\\r\\n` it also works.

Comment: In addition, I think `\\n([^\\n]*\\n)+?` is more clear and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of wasting time, I finally found a solution that would fit.
There are two regex that would fit in this solution.

```
Solution 1 : < *Directory */? *>(\\n|.*)+?</Directory>
```

I used the | (OR) in the capture group with a lazy (?) operator to stop with the first match. However, the regex that I posted in the question seems to be working fine in all regex testers.

```
Solution 2 : < *Directory */? *>(\\s|\\S)+?</Directory>
```

Just replaced the newline and any character (.) with \s and \S.

However, it is known that (\s|\S) is same as [\s\S] but it looks like the capture group works but the second one does not.

I don't have any idea how it happens!